# communication between two computers via Python socket in a LAN failed

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp

Two computers in a LAN connecting to a wireless router, one IP address is 192.168.1.106 (server), the other one is 192.168.1.107 (client), the gateway on both computer is 192.168.1.1 (the router itself).

The two computer can ping each in two directions which means there should be no problem with routing and the router itself. But I failed when I tried to use Python UDP socket, the server cannot get any information from the client, and same happened when I change the ip address. (But it works fine when server and client are on a same computer using local ip address, so the code is should be ok)

I am using the following code:

server:

```
import socket

address = ('192.168.1.106', 5678) # the server listening on address 192.168.1.106
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(address)

while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(2048)
    if data == "empty":
        print "no data from client"
    else:
        print "received:", data, "from", addr

s.close()
```

client:

```
import socket

address = ('192.168.1.106', 5678)  # the client send to address 192.168.1.106
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:
    msg = raw_input()
    if not msg:
        msg = "empty"
    s.sendto(msg, address)

s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you open the UDP port on the firewall on both comoutera?

Comment: yes of course, the firewall allows any kinds of flows

Comment: 1) Turn both firewalls off and test it.

Comment: 2) Send a very small datagram. Maybe it is dropping.